# Pipe serial dump to SD card file

Tags: serial, sd-card

I am using the RFID module to read mifare NFC chips and the library has only methods to send the data to the serial monitor. I need them to be saved to an SD card file. I have been adding custom methods to the library files to return strings that I then write to the SD card but this is a pain; there must be a quicker way to simply pipe all the data automatically but I do not know how to do this in cpp.

Here is an example of the function to dump to serial, that needs to be piped to the file on the SD card.

```
void MFRC522::PICC_DumpDetailsToSerial(Uid *uid) {
    Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));
    for (byte i = 0; i < uid->size; i++) {
        if(uid->uidByte[i] < 0x10)
            Serial.print(F(" 0"));
        else
            Serial.print(F(" "));
        Serial.print(uid->uidByte[i], HEX);
    } 
    Serial.println();

    // SAK
    Serial.print(F("Card SAK: "));
    if(uid->sak < 0x10)
        Serial.print(F("0"));
    Serial.println(uid->sak, HEX);

    // (suggested) PICC type
    PICC_Type piccType = PICC_GetType(uid->sak);
    Serial.print(F("PICC type: "));
    Serial.println(PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: the arduino does not have an operating system, so there is no "pipe" as is in linux ....... maybe there is a way to redefine the Serial object

Answer (score 1):

Have the MFRC522 objects remember where you want them to send the output
by adding a data member to the class like this:

```c++
private:
    Print &output;
```

This is a reference to a `Print` object, i.e. any object where you can
`print()` or `println()` to. This reference should be initialized in the
constructor, like this

```c++
MFRC522:MFRC522(...other arguments..., Print &my_output = Serial)
: ...other initializations..., output(my_output)
{
    ...constructor body...
}
```

Notice that, by default, the `output` is initialiazed as a reference to
`Serial`. Thus, unless you explicitly ask for the output to go
elsewhere, the class will behave as before.

Last step is to change, in the implementation of the class, *every*
reference to `Serial` by `output`. This is just a global find and
replace.

At this point, the `MFRC522` class can be used exactly as before, and it
will behave identically. This means that *every* user of the library
should be able to use your modified version with no issues. I thus
encourage you to submit the changes to the original author, so that they
have a chance to be incorporated into the canonical version of the
library.

Now, if you want this debugging output to be sent elsewhere, just
provide the destination as the last argument of the constructor:

```c++
MFRC522 my_RFID_module(...other arguments..., my_SD_card_file);
```

As long as the destination is an instance of the `Print` virtual class
(basically anything you can `print()` to should be OK), it should work
as expected.